# Discord bot indentation

Tags: python, discord.py

Unexpected indentation
"await" allowed only within async function
Unindent not expected
"message" is not defined
"message" is not defined

```
import discord
import requests
import json

TOKEN = ''

client = discord.Client(command_prefix='&')

def get_info():
  info = requests.get('https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/periodic-table/#view=list/api/random').json()

    if message.content.startswith('&Element'):
        await message.channel.send(info)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: 
        return

    if message.content.startswith('&hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: If that's your exact code, then the `info = ...` line needs two additional spaces, to line up with the `if message.contents...` line.  Indentation is syntax in Python, and things need to line up.  In addition, as the message says, you are using `await` in `get_info`, even though it is not an `async` function, and yes, `message` is not defined in that function.  Did you intend to pass it in as a parameter?  Right now, you aren't even calling that function.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is when you say &Element it prints out a random element and all of its information

Comment: So, you need to add another `elif` clause to `on_message`.  That `elif` clause can then call your `get_info_ function to fetch the element.  You will probably want to extract the element name, rather than just send back the raw return.  BTW, have you looked at the HTML you get back from that request?  The page is entirely created with Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a `get_info` function. You can write that code in your `on_message` function. You could do something like this, just like you did for `&hello`

```
if message.content.startswith('&Element'):
        info = requests.get('https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/periodic-table/#view=list/api/random').json()
        await message.reply(info)
```